# Is my betta fish dead?

Tags: betta

I just got my fish yesterday and he hasn't been moving much later that night he sat at the bottom of the tank and I thought he was sleeping the next day he was still in the bottom of the tank what do I do? Is he too cold? Is he dead or dying? Is he sick? Please help!

Comment: Please give some more information. How long do you have your aquarium, did you cycle it, what's the temperature, how big is your tank,... ?

Comment: Have you asked the folks you bought the fish from?

Answer (score 1):

If he is still alive you should be able to see his gills moving.  
But please give some more information about your tank to be able to help you identify why he is probably suffering from something.